# how to save data without using database?

Tags: django

hello guys so i made this website that intergrate with my router to manage the user inside it,but i have this question i want to ask
so my website only visualise the data that it got from the router and i have this voucher system to give out voucher to the user
to access the network as right now i save this voucher in my database but due to each of the voucher data that it i save to the database and from the database it display to the web, it all from data that it got from the router<-- and here
come the problem is that the data is not valid because if the admin access the router and delete one of the voucher profile it will cause and error,because the voucher in database is been deleted from the router,
is there any way i can do this so that i dont need to use database to save this? thanks

Comment: you may serialize the data - python  -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try storing it in files. but its not reliable, and not as efficient as storing in database. its also not ass fast. it takes more time to update file than update database. so db is your best and only option.